# Unable to exclude c3p0

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have the following gradle config (based on [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:working_with_dependencies)):

```
  compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'c3p0'
  }
  compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'c3p0'
  }
```

I've also tried:

```
  compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'c3p0', module: 'c3p0'
  }
  compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'c3p0', module: 'c3p0'
  }
```

and yet I still get

```
+--- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.12
|    \--- c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.1
```

when I list dependencies (and the jar shows up in my war file).

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.2 x86_64
```

This is an issue since the hibernate libs reference 0.9.2.1 c3p0 but it has a different group (com.mchange), so regular dependency preference for new versions isn't happening. I'm having odd closed statement connection pooling errors despite having configured for verification of connections on checkout. The code that is throwing it has all been managed by JPA, I don't call close anywhere...  So I want to get c3p0 cleaned up here to ensure it's not a problem stemming from mixed versions on the class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I used Michael Easter's bare bones template as a start and incrementally added stuff. The problem returned when I added a dependency on JesterJ... That results in this (many irrelevant libs omitted):

```
+--- org.jesterj:injest:0.2-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.12
|    |    +--- edu.ucar:netcdf4:4.5.5
|    |    |    +--- edu.ucar:cdm:4.5.5
|    |    |    |    +--- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.0 -> 2.2.3 (*)
```

and as soon as the 2.2.0 (for which 2.2.3 is duly substituted) is in there, it restores the dependency on the older c3p0

```
+--- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.12
|    \--- c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.1
```

If I exclude the tika dependency from JesterJ then everything is fine again:

```
  compile('org.jesterj:injest:0.2-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group:"org.apache.tika"
  }
```

gets me back to

```
+--- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.12
```

This looks like a bug in gradle to me since dependencies from version X which is replaced by Y should not be adding their dependencies to Y, but rather relying on Y to properly handle it's own dependencies.

The final solution is:

1. If trying to exclude c3p0 in a situation like this, (or another lib in a similar situation) look for parent dependencies of c3p0 that are replacing dependencies elsewhere in the application.
2. Exclude c3p0 from the parent of the replaced dependency as well.

My exclusion of Tika above is too heavy handed (I actually need that!) The parsimonious solution looked like this: (for the libraries involved)

```
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:4.3.11.Final'
  compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3') {
    exclude group: 'c3p0'
  }
  compile 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.2.3'
  compile('org.jesterj:injest:0.2-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group:"c3p0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that your entire Gradle file? Using Gradle 3.3, this works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3') {
        exclude group: 'c3p0'
    }
    compile ('org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.2.3') {
        exclude group: 'c3p0'
    }
}
```

If I comment-out the `exclude` then I see the `c3p0` jar listed in `gradle dependencies` ; as it is above, I do not.